# Chromium Error :- 6 Charts.js/Chartnew.js

Tags: javascript, android, charts, android-webview

I am trying to use the Charts.js library in my android app inside a webview. I tried changing it to chartsnew.js library too, but I get the same error and the chart does not load in my app.

D/chromium: Unknown chromium error: -6

I have tried searching all forums and questions posted before, tried double checking that the URL to my file is correct and that the JavaScript is also enabled inside.

The app originally used an ajax request to pull data, but since things were not working I tried putting the static data. The graphs load and show if I open the file directly in chrome. But shows a blank canvas in android webview.

HTML File attached :

```
   <html>
<head>


    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../general/js/ChartNew.js"></script>
    <script src="../general/js/shapesInChart.js"></script>


    <style>
        canvas {
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        }
    </style>

    </head>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


$(document).ready(function() {

   options = {

    //Boolean - If we show the scale above the chart data
    scaleOverlay : false,

    //Boolean - If we want to override with a hard coded scale
    scaleOverride : false,

    //** Required if scaleOverride is true **
    //Number - The number of steps in a hard coded scale
    scaleSteps : null,
    //Number - The value jump in the hard coded scale
    scaleStepWidth : null,
    //Number - The scale starting value
    scaleStartValue : null,

    //String - Colour of the scale line
    scaleLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.1)",

    //Number - Pixel width of the scale line
    scaleLineWidth : 1,

    //Boolean - Whether to show labels on the scale
    scaleShowLabels : false,

    //Interpolated JS string - can access value
    scaleLabel : "<%=value%>",

    //String - Scale label font declaration for the scale label
    scaleFontFamily : "'Arial'",

    //Number - Scale label font size in pixels
    scaleFontSize : 12,

    //String - Scale label font weight style
    scaleFontStyle : "normal",

    //String - Scale label font colour
    scaleFontColor : "#666",

    ///Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
    scaleShowGridLines : true,

    //String - Colour of the grid lines
    scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",

    //Number - Width of the grid lines
    scaleGridLineWidth : 1,

    //Boolean - If there is a stroke on each bar
    barShowStroke : true,

    //Number - Pixel width of the bar stroke
    barStrokeWidth : 2,

    //Number - Spacing between each of the X value sets
    barValueSpacing : 5,

    //Number - Spacing between data sets within X values
    barDatasetSpacing : 1,

    //Boolean - Whether to animate the chart
    animation : true,

    //Number - Number of animation steps
    animationSteps : 60,

    //String - Animation easing effect
    animationEasing : "easeOutQuart",

    //Function - Fires when the animation is complete
    onAnimationComplete : null

};

    var data = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
        }
    ]
                }

    ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, options);

});

</script>
</html>
```

EDIT 1 :

ok So I was not able to load the local HTML file inside the android web-view, no matter what I tried. But then I still moved ahead and tried to modify my code to get the dynamic data from an ajax request. Surprisingly, it has started working on the dynamic data

Here is my code for the dynamic pull :

```
<html>
<head>


    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../general/js/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="../general/js/Chartjs.js"></script>


    <style>
        canvas {
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<canvas id="myChart" width="350" height="350"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var id=replaceName;
var regDate = replaceDate;

$(document).ready(function() {



$.ajax({
        url:"<serverurl>customer/betGetBloodPressure.jsp",
        data:{"id":id,"regDate":regDate},
        type:"post",
        dataType:"jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",
        success: function(res) {

        options = {

    //Boolean - If we show the scale above the chart data
    scaleOverlay : false,

    //Boolean - If we want to override with a hard coded scale
    scaleOverride : true,

    //** Required if scaleOverride is true **
    //Number - The number of steps in a hard coded scale
    scaleSteps : 3,
    //Number - The value jump in the hard coded scale
    scaleStepWidth : 50,
    //Number - The scale starting value
    scaleStartValue : 0,

    //String - Colour of the scale line
    scaleLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.1)",

    //Number - Pixel width of the scale line
    scaleLineWidth : 1,

    //Boolean - Whether to show labels on the scale
    scaleShowLabels : true,

    //Interpolated JS string - can access value
    scaleLabel : "<%=value%>",

    //String - Scale label font declaration for the scale label
    scaleFontFamily : "'sans-serif'",

    //Number - Scale label font size in pixels
    scaleFontSize : 12,

    //String - Scale label font weight style
    scaleFontStyle : "normal",

    //String - Scale label font colour
    scaleFontColor : "#666",

    ///Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
    scaleShowGridLines : true,

    //String - Colour of the grid lines
    scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",

    //Number - Width of the grid lines
    scaleGridLineWidth : 1,

    //Boolean - If there is a stroke on each bar
    barShowStroke : true,

    //Number - Pixel width of the bar stroke
    barStrokeWidth : 2,

    //Number - Spacing between each of the X value sets
    barValueSpacing : 5,

    //Number - Spacing between data sets within X values
    barDatasetSpacing : 0,

    //Boolean - Whether to animate the chart
    animation : true,

    //Number - Number of animation steps
    animationSteps : 60,

    //String - Animation easing effect
    animationEasing : "easeOutQuart",

    //Function - Fires when the animation is complete
    onAnimationComplete : null,

    spaceBetweenBar : 0 ,

    // String or array - fill color when hovered
    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",

    // String or array - border color when hovered
    hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)"
};


    var data = {
    labels : ['MIN BP', 'AVERAGE BP', 'MAX BP'],
    datasets :
    [
        {
            label: 'Max Average Of Age #',
            fillColor: '#a280ff',
            data: [parseInt(res.aoa_lower_low),parseInt(res.aoa_avg_low),parseInt(res.aoa_higer_low)],
            yAxisID: "y-axis-0"
        },
        {
            label: 'My Info. #',
            fillColor: '#7c4dff',
            data: [parseInt(res.my_low),parseInt(res.my_avg),parseInt(res.my_high)]
        },
         {
            label: 'Min Average Of Age #',
            fillColor: '#6933ff',
            data: [parseInt(res.aoa_lower_high),parseInt(res.aoa_avg_high),parseInt(res.aoa_higer_high)]
          }
    ]
        };

        scaleSteps = 10;

    ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data,options);

    }
});

});

</script>
</html>
```

Now am struggling with one last problem, as seen in the screenshot my graph appears, but am not able to show the label values which can show me what each of my color indicates defined as the "label" parameter in the above code inside the datasets. Looks like I am missing something I need to define in my options, but not able to find out what. Please help

[Graph pulled from AJAX Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPPPJ.png)

Comment: Have you put the html page in the assets folder? Where is the js?

Comment: Yes the HTML page is in the assets folder and the URL is correctly called I/url: file:///android_asset/hellog_chart/bloodPresure.html ...... The js is also under the assets folder ... Assets --> general---> JS

Comment: Have you added INTERNET permission in manifest?

Comment: Yes it is there... The other sections are using jqchart libraries and working fine. But since that is a paid library, I am trying to switch to an open source one.

Comment: Is there any other js error other than the one mentioned?

Comment: Nope. That's the only one I can see. And as I said when I try to run that HTML file directly I do get a graph on google chrome, just not on the web-view.

Answer (score 1):

okay so I finally found the solution to the problem of my second EDIT in which label values descriptions for my color was not showing up.

Just added :

```
multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %> - <%= value %>"
```

to my options. And awesome it works now. :)

[Working Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOufv.png)